# Parcel build is failing `bundle.scss:undefined:undefined: plugin is not a function`

Tags: reactjs, sass, postcss, parceljs

I am using parcel bundler for my learning project and trying to create build for it. I am also using scss file. In `bundle.scss` I have imported all of my scss files.
And importing `bundle.scss` into `App.js`.

So while running `parcel build index.html`, i am getting following error.

```
  /src/style/bundle.scss:undefined:undefined: plugin is not a function
    at LazyResult.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parcel-bundler/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:288:14)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parcel-bundler/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:212:26)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/parcel-bundler/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:254:14
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at LazyResult.async (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parcel-bundler/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:250:23)
    at LazyResult.then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parcel-bundler/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:131:17)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! xxxxx complete: `parcel build index.html`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the xxxxx complete script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /.npm/_logs/2021-06-12T17_37_55_156Z-debug.log
```

My project structure

```
src/
-App.js
-styles/
--bundle.scss
--app.scss
-index.html
```

Any suggestion would be real help for me, Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

It seems to be a bug in Parcel's `nanocss`. I could only fix it by not minifying the css at all, using

```
parcel build --no-minify
```

Comment: It's a mess, this also does not minify the js too

Comment: It seems to be problem of old version, with the new `npm i parcel` this issue seems to be resolve.

Comment: This fixed my problem building Vue 2 with parcel-bundler (can't upgrade to Vue 3 yet). Yeah, Parcel 2 does NOT support Vue 2 anymore, lovely.

Answer (score 6):

**You don't have to remove your minification, there's another way..**

you cannot see `cssnano version` because it's under the hood.
There's a bug with the current `parcel bundler version` & the current `cssnano version`.

*you can fix this by downgrading cssnano*

```
npm uninstall cssnano
npm i -D cssnano@4.1.11
```

now try rebuilding it with `parcel build <your path>`, it should work.

Answer (score 4):

You can still use parcel-bundler if you [downgrade cssnano](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/2505#issuecomment-859025313) to 4.1.11.

Probably the only reason to do this is if you are using Vue SFCs.